# Stripe how to get subscription interval

Tags: php, stripes, stripe-payments

Is there a clean way to get the current subscription interval without checking the items?

For now i am looking in the first items of the subscription and retrieve the price to get the recurring interval

```
function getSubscriptionItemInterval($items){
    $priceId = $items[0]->price->id;
    
    $price = $this->_stripe->prices->retrieve( $priceId);
    $intervalPrice = $price->recurring->interval;
    return $intervalPrice;
}
```